# Convert post name into post ID

Tags: slug

I am trying to create a function for my functions.php file that will allow me to convert a post name into a post id.  I have had a look around online and managed to find this link http://www.devdevote.com/cms/wordpress-hacks/get_id_by_post_name which gives the following example..

```
function get_id_by_post_name($post_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$post_name."'");
    return $id;
}

<?php echo get_id_by_post_name('my-post-name'); ?>
```

After replacing **my-post-name** in the example I am not getting any results, can anyone suggest what is wrong?

I was also looking into the get_by_postname function in case this was a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/). It works with any post type.

```
$post = get_page_by_title( $post_name, OBJECT, 'post' );
echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: I am now trying to move on with this function and convert it so that it uses the post name instead of the Id.  I have created a new question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59050/combine-two-functions-highlight-menu-item-by-post-name-instead-of-id  -  Any chance you could look in?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `get_page_by_path()` is the function you'd use to do a lookup by `post_name` (or a slash separated hierarchy of them), and `get_page_by_title()` would work only for `post_title`.