# Highlighting a Menu Item by Post Name

Tags: admin-menu

With the help of a couple of users, my last two questions were highlighting a custom menu item through its ID.

Now I'm trying to combine the code of the following two functions to make it work by Post Name:

[Add highlighting to new Admin Dashboard Menu Item](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58567/add-highlighting-to-new-admin-dashboard-menu-item)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'create_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_58567_highlight_menu_item' );

function create_menu() {
    $settings_page = add_menu_page(
                                   'Edit_Post_69', 
                                   'Edit_Post_69', 
                                   'add_users', 
                                   '/post.php?post=69&action=edit', 
                                   '', 
                                   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/editicon.png', 
                                   2
                                  );
}

function wpse_58567_highlight_menu_item() {
    global $post;

    if( 69 != $post->ID )
        return;
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $('#toplevel_page_post-post-69-action-edit').removeClass('wp-not-current-submenu').addClass('current');
            $('#toplevel_page_post-post-69-action-edit').find('a:last').addClass('current');
        });     
    </script>
<?php
}
```

and....

[Convert post name into post ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58943/convert-post-name-into-post-id/58944#58944)

```
$post = get_page_by_title( $post_name, OBJECT, 'post' );
echo $post->ID;
```

I am now trying to combine them so that I can specify a post name instead of a post ID, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ain't the Question missing the `add_menu_page` code? Because, [in the previous Q](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58567/), this extra menu item (linking to the page in question, 69) had the ID hardcoded as well...

Comment: Yeah missed that out,  I have edited the question to put it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attention to the use of [**`get_page_by_title`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) parameters.

And also to the use of the [**Heredoc PHP**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

```
$the_post_title = 'The Portfolio';

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_59050_add_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_59050_highlight_menu_item' );

function wpse_59050_add_menu() 
{
    global $the_post_title;
    $our_page = get_page_by_title( $the_post_title );

    $settings_page = add_menu_page( 'Edit '.$our_page->post_title, 'Edit '.$our_page->post_title, 'add_users', '/post.php?post='.$our_page->ID.'&action=edit', '', '', 2);
}

function wpse_59050_highlight_menu_item()
{
    global $the_post_title, $post;

    if( !is_object( $post ) )
        return;

    $our_page = get_page_by_title( $the_post_title );

    if( $our_page->ID != $post->ID )
        return;

    echo <<<HTML
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                $('#toplevel_page_post-post-{$our_page->ID}-action-edit').removeClass('wp-not-current-submenu').addClass('current');
                $('#toplevel_page_post-post-{$our_page->ID}-action-edit').find('a:last').addClass('current');
            });     
        </script>
HTML;
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: I am trying to apply that but am getting an error Call to undefined function loga()

Comment: Ups... It's a Firephp custom debug function... Obviously an alien: `loga('aaaa');` ?! . . . . Answer corrected ;)

Comment: Ahhh i see, all working now :)  Thanks for helping out with that one again.  Also thanks to TheDeadMedic for his original solution.

Comment: I would add an `is_object( $post )` to your highlight condition for safe measure.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - Like that? . . . I didn't know this function, in what cases would `$post` not be an object? . . . Thx

Comment: `$post` won't always be set, so you'll throw a notice like "Undefined variable" & "Trying to get property of non-object" with `WP_DEBUG`. But more importantly, it's just good practice :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that and also for the `class WPSE_59050`..!

Answer (score 4):

There's a much easier way for setting the current menu context - the `parent_file` filter.

```
add_filter( 'parent_file', array( 'WPSE_59050', 'parent_file' ) );
add_action( 'admin_menu',  array( 'WPSE_59050', 'admin_menu' ) );

class WPSE_59050
{
    /**
     * The title of the post to add our menu item for.
     */
    const POST_TITLE = 'My Post Title';

    /**
     * Our cached post ID from title.
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    private static $_post_id;

    /**
     * Correctly set the menu context if we're editing our post.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function parent_file( $parent_file )
    {
        global $pagenow;

        if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' && isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && $_REQUEST['post'] == self::get_post_id() )
            $parent_file = "post.php?post={$_REQUEST['post']}&action=edit";

        return $parent_file;
    }

    /**
     * Add the menu item if the post can be found.
     */
    public static function admin_menu()
    {
        if ( $post_id = self::get_post_id() )
            add_menu_page( 'Edit ' . self::POST_TITLE, 'Edit ' . self::POST_TITLE, 'add_users', "/post.php?post=$post_id&action=edit" );
    }

    /**
     * Get our post ID from the title & cache it.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public static function get_post_id()
    {
        if ( ! isset( self::$_post_id ) ) {
            if ( $post = get_page_by_title( self::POST_TITLE, OBJECT, 'post' ) )
                self::$_post_id = $post->ID;
            else
                self::$_post_id = null;
        }

        return self::$_post_id;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Changed menu & page title to use post title, rather than ID.

Comment: Wooow, that's beautiful, TheDeadMedic!¡ :o) . . . Just tested and ain't working for me, and it'd be da bomb to see it! . . . I already have a working code with the brute-force-method, but will hold it until we have this one :) . . . . The end result has to be like [this snapshot](http://cl.ly/image/101H0m1k3A2T).

Comment: In `get_post_id()`, change `'post'` to `'page'` ;)

Comment: Whoops, I should note this *replaces* the highlighting - if you want *both*, I think you'll have to fallback to your JS proposal.

Comment: mmmm, cannot investigate this right now, I'll post my solution and return to this in other moment... Or maybe @fightstarr20 can merge the codes and propose a 3rd Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'parent_file_hover' );
function parent_file_hover( $parent_file )   {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php')
        $parent_file = "post.php?post={$_REQUEST['post']}&action=edit";
    elseif($pagenow == 'post-new.php')
        $parent_file = "post-new.php?post_type={$_REQUEST['post_type']}";
    return $parent_file;
}
```

Comment: An explanation could turn that into an answer. :)